# How to read a file with more than one tab as separator and where the space is part of column value

Tags: r

I have to read a CSV file with tab (`"\t"`) separator and it can occur multiple times. The `read.table` function has the special white space separator (`sep=""`) that considers multiple occurrences of any whitespace (tab or space). The problem is that I have the space character as part of the column value, so I cannot use the white space separator. When I use `"\t"` it only consider one occurrence.

Here is a toy example of my problem:

```
text1 <- "
a   b   c
11  12      13
21  22  23
"
ds <- read.csv(sep = "", text = text1)
```

before the element [1,3], i.e. `"13"` there are two tabs as separator. Then I get:

```
   a  b  c
1 11 12 13
2 21 22 23
```

This is the **expected result**.

Let's say we add an space in the third column values between the first and second number, so now it would be: `"1 3"` and `"2 3"`. Now we cannot use a white space delimiter because the space is not a delimiter in this case, it is part of the column value. Now when I use `"\t"` I get this **unexpected result**:

```
text3 <- "
a   b   c
11  12      1 3
21  22  2 3
"
ds <- read.csv(sep = "\t", text = text3)
```

The string representation of the input text is:

```
"a\tb\tc\n11\t12\t\t1 3\n21\t22\t2 3\n"
```

And now the result is:

```
    a   b   c
11 12     1 3
21 22 23
```

It seems to be simple, but I cannot find a way to do it using the `read.table` interface, because the input argument `sep` does not accept a regular expression as delimiter.

Comment: @G5W I think it is not the same the problem the one you are reffering is for more than one **different** separator. My case is one character separator (`"\t"`) with more than one occurrence.

Comment: I agree with you David, one suggestion would be to open the file in a basic text editor and find and replace the out of place separators with the more common separators. I commonly use Notepad++ to achieve this result, however I'm sure there must be a way to read this information in as text, `gsub()` then turn it into a data.frame.

Comment: @Badger that should be a good solution, but this is just a toy example, I have more than 500 files with the same pattern.

Comment: Can you confirm that other separations are only double spaces with the odd tab?

Comment: @Badger, yes, the odd table has one or two tabs as delimiter and then and the column values from the third column has one space as part of the cell value. Copy and paste from stackoverflow does not preserve the tab, but adding the tab it can be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a workaround for this, 1) replacing all extra tabs with one first, 2) read the file/text. For example:

```
read.csv(text = gsub("[\t]+", "\t", readLines(text3), perl = TRUE), sep = "\t")
```

and also using a file instead:

```
temp <- tempfile()
writeLines(text3, temp)
read.csv(text = gsub("[\t]+", "\t", readLines(temp), perl = TRUE), sep = "\t")
```

The `text` input argument will result:

```
> text
[1] "a\tb\tc"     "11\t12\t1 3" "21\t22\t2 3" ""
```

and the result of `read.csv` will be:

```
   a  b   c
1 11 12 1 3
2 21 22 2 3
```

This is similar to @Badger suggestion, just in one step.

Comment: Very nice! I'll be dissecting this tomorrow, nice work.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I've got something for you:

```
write.table( gsub("\\r","", gsub("\t","", readChar( "C:/_Localdata/tab_sep.txt", file.info( "C:/_Localdata/tab_sep.txt" )$size) ) ), "C:/_Localdata/test.txt", sep=" ", quote = F, col.names = T, row.names=F)

## In the event there is a possibility that it is 1 or 2 tabs in series, you can use gsub("\t|\t\t", in place of gsub("\t", just add a | and more \t's if needed!

read.table("C:/_Localdata/test.txt",sep=" ",skip=1,header=T)
```

Okay what just happened? First we read in the file as a massive character string using readChar(), we need to tell R how big the file is, using file.info(), from this we need to get rid of any tabs using gsub and the \t call, then we have a character string with \r's and \n's, the \r and \n are both carriage returns however R sees both within the file, so it reports both. As such we get rid of one of the carriage returns. Then we write the table out (ideally back to where it came from). Now you can read it in with an easy separating value of a single space, and skip the first line. The first line will be an X, an artifact of writing out a gsub. Also declare a header and you should be good to go!

Let's say you have 500 files.

Place all your files in a folder, and set the pattern to the file type they are, or just allow R to view them all by removing the pattern call.

```
for( filename in 1:list.files("C:_/Localdata/",patten=".txt") ) {
    write.table( gsub("\\r","", gsub("\t","", readChar( filename , file.info( filename  )$size) ) ), filename , sep=" ", quote = F, col.names = T, row.names=F)
}
```

Now your files are ready to be read in however you would like.

Comment: I see your second problem with a tab and a space. This would require that you have a multiple space delimiter between standard columns. You would need to change those to a unique character to then handle the stray spaces. A complex problem, but the solution is relatively simple.